# Display Pointer only once?

Tags: themes

I am using following code to display a pointer on the post edit page. It displays the pointer everytime the page is load. Is there way to stop it displaying everytime? (eg. display only when the page is loaded first time?, not everytime when the post is saved or page is reloaded etc)?

```
$('#some-button').pointer({
    content: '<?php echo $pointer_content; ?>',
    position: {
        edge: 'left',
        align: 'center'
    },
    close: function() {
        // Once the close button is hit
    }
}).pointer('open');
```

Comment: Define "first time". First time ever? First time every day? First time for every user opening a post?

Comment: I don't agree this is off-topic for lack of WP context. Pointers are quite specific to it. If I were to close vote, it would be "unclear of what you're asking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the pointer is to update the user meta when the pointer is closed.  This is what will prevent the pointer from displaying on every page load.  Once the user clicks "Close".. that user meta pointer key is updated.

So, add a post method to your close function:

```
close: function() {
    // Once the close button is hit
    $.post (ajaxurl, {
        pointer: 'dismiss_my_pointer',
        action: 'dismiss-wp-pointer'
    });
}
```

Then, in the page where you are calling the pointer, you need to enqueue the necessary files:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts () {
    $dismissed = explode (',', get_user_meta (wp_get_current_user ()->ID, 'dismissed_wp_pointers', true));
    $not_in_array = !in_array ('dismiss_my_pointer', $dismissed);
    if ($not_in_array) {
        wp_enqueue_style ('wp-pointer');
        wp_enqueue_script ('wp-pointer');
        wp_enqueue_script ('utils');
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');
```

NOTE 1: You need to run a check to make sure you are only enqueueing this script on the page where you need.

NOTE 2: The `ajaxurl` in the post request might first need to be defined (if using this on the viewer side).  You can define a global namespaced variable to pass the url to your js file.

Comment: Exactly, I think the idea behind the pointers is to annoy you until you click the damn close button, the sooner the better, if it is on the first time it pops up, mission accomplished :)

Comment: Haha, yup!  Just imagine if everyone figured out the 'tour' usage ;)  Pointers everywhere.. AHHHH!!